# how to filter pods against multiple label selectors with terratest?

Tags: go, kubernetes, terratest

I have a code that uses `k8s` module of `terratest` to list pods based on label selector.

```
pods, err := k8s.ListPodsE(
    t,
    k8soptions,
    filter,
)
```

where the filter is initialized with a string labelSelector like this,

```
filter := metav1.ListOptions{
        LabelSelector: "kubeslice.io/app=foo",
}
```

So if I want to filter pods against more than one labels, say pods which has both`kubeslice.io/pod-type=gateway` & `kubeslice.io/app=foo`, how can I achieve that in this method ?

Comment: You should try a comma separated string, like 'kubeslice.io/app=foo,kubeslice.io/app=bar'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [doublethink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13294769/doublethink) and I tested, we could provide a comma separated string of label selectors like this.

```
filter := metav1.ListOptions{
        LabelSelector: "kubeslice.io/app=foo,kubeslice.io/app=bar",
}
```